# How to use a regex to find combined words with period delimiters?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all instances of words separated by period delimiters.

So for example, these would be valid:

```
word1.word2
word1.word2.word3
word1.word2.word3.word4
```

Valid letters of words are those composed of `a-zA-Z0-9-`.
And so on. I tried `[\w.]*` but this does not appear to be accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+(?:\.\w+)+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/8)

Comment: This also returns standalone words that have no periods. My difficulty has been enforcing the period delimiter.

Comment: @user64283 `(?=.*\.)` this will make sure that there is atleast one period in the string :)

Comment: @user64283 is this allowed? `word.word.` or `word..word`

Comment: the word must be at least one character, so `word..word` is invalid. the period must delimit the words, so `word.word.` is invalid too. Just `word.` at least 1 time (but possibly many), ending with another `word`

Comment: @user64283: is the dash allowed at the begining or the end of a word?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Hmmm, I'd say no. Somewhere in the middle probably.

Comment: is there a way to do something like `[[\w]+.]+`, trying to say "a word with at least one character, followed by a period, and this pattern overall can be repeated, but must show up at least once?

Comment: @user64283 yes.. check my answer.. `(?:\.\w+)+` will do that but in a different way :)

Comment: For some reason not working when I use re.findall(), not sure why. Does it have something to with using `^` and `$`?

Comment: yes.. if you have multiple occurances remove start and end anchors.. (`^` and `$`)

Comment: Accepted as answer. Would love to know how `(?:\.\w+)+` works if you'd be willing to explain!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78467/discussion-between-karthik-manchala-and-user64283).